# Bing Map on Safari (iPhone). Keyboard pops when clicking on the map

Tags: javascript, iphone, bing-maps

I've integrated Bing Maps into a web page using javascript. Simple integration of Bing Maps.

I'm having an issue where when they click on the map, the keyboard comes up (on an iphone). How can I stop BingMaps from popping up the keyboard?

Thanks,
Gob

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but I just ran into this problem and figured out the solution:

Bing maps allows keyboard shortcuts (i.e. you can type R, A or H to switch to Road View, Aerial View or Hybrid View, respectively). To do this, it seems like they add a transparent input field nested inside the div you render the map in. Because of this, on iOS devices, tapping the map causes the keyboard to appear since it thinks the user is typing in a text field.

To fix this, simply add the following CSS:

```css
#wl_ve_mapInput { display:none !important }
```

This will hide the text field and stop the iOS keyboard from appearing when tapping the map. This problem also occurs on Android devices.

**NOTE:**
Obviously, you will no longer be able to use the keyboard shortcuts. A possible approach would be to add some code to only add the CSS if it's a mobile browser, or only iOS devices. This is fairly easy to figure out, but it's not part of the scope of the original question.